# PHP Submit main form and javascript triggered secondary form not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have been working on this for days and can't seem to get to the bottom of it.

Ive reduced the problem to this.

I have this form as shown below:

```
<body>

    <form name="record" method="post" action="process.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="email_address" />
        <input type="hidden" name="postcode" />
    </form>
    <!--
        function doLogin() {
        document.record.submit();
        }
    //-->
    </script>
<!-- $(endif) -->

<table width="100%" style="margin-top: 10%;">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
    <br />
    <table width="240" height="240" style="border: 1px solid #ffcccc; 
padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0">
    <td align="center" valign="bottom" style="padding-top: 5px; 
padding-bottom: 5px;" height="175" colspan="2">

        <form name="login" action="<?php echo $linkloginonly; ?>" 
method="post" onSubmit="return doLogin()" >
            <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="<?php echo 
$linkorig; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
            <table width="100" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-
bottom: 5px;"
                <tr align="center" valign="top" height="50" 
colspan="2" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><img 
src="wi.png" height="41" width="200" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-
bottom: 5px;"></tr>
                <tr style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 
5px;"><img src="home.jpg" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 
5px;"></tr>
                <div class="notice" style="color: #039bc3; font-size: 
9px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">Free WiFi<br 
/><br />Please enter a few quick details</div>

                <tr><td align="right">Email</td>
                <td><input style="width: 140px" 
name="email_address" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td align="right">Postcode</td>
                <td><input style="width: 140px" name="postcode" 
type="text"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td> </td>

                <td><input type="submit" value="Continue" 
/></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<!-- $(if error) -->
<br /><div style="color: #FF8080; font-size: 9px"><?php echo $error; 
?></div>
<!-- $(endif) -->

    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 document.login.username.focus();
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On click, the form should call doLogin() which should submit the form called record and pass email_address and postcode to a database via process.php

Ive proved this part works if I just call process.php from the main form by amending the action part and removing onSubmit rather than using doLogin() but I can't seem to get it to work this way as shown. I need to get it working this way so I can build more functionality in.

Could somebody help please?

Comment: you want 2 forms submitting?  I have usually(in the past) used an onsubmit method to return false if it needs more data.  submitting another form inside another form's onsubmit may not make sense.  perhaps describe what you want to happen and why in the question. btw, welcome to SO.

Comment: It might help if I broaden things out to show my full intention.

I'm using login.php from the following page [link](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/HotSpot_external_login_page)

Im trying to add my own functionality to this so that the modified file does the same things but also passes the two form entries to a database on the same server. 

Oh and thanks for the welcome :)

Comment: in that case, I would suggest making the main form's button a simple button instead of a submit...with a handler "main_form_go" which performs a remote request with the data you want...and when that request is done(in it's callback function), submit the main form.  you'll want jquery or axios to make your life easier.

Comment: @user1269942   Ive been trying this but with no luck. Would you mind posting an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you problem come when you added a new form, that the reason why now isn't running. When you add a second form to the same page the form call in js change to :

document.form[index] in you case :

```
//if you want call <form name="record" // first form = index 0
document.forms[0].submit();
//or
document.forms["record"].submit();
//or
document.record.submit();
//if you want call <form name="login" //second form = index 1
document.forms[1].submit();
//or
document.forms["login"].submit();
//or
document.login.submit();
//etc ...
```

Regards.

Comment: Hey headmax, thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. I fear I may have confused the issue by trying to truncate the problem description. If I have I apologise. I will ultimately be calling 2 forms from the onSubmit() function by trying to use a javascript function for each. I've tried doing this with document.login.submit in the doLogin() function and document.record.submit in the doRecord() function. That too didn't work.

Are you saying that naming my function doLogin() somehow ties it to the form "login"?

Comment: Hi there, I changed the function to the following:

function doLogin() {
  document.forms["record"].submit();
     }

It still didn't work :-(

Comment: Sorry i was not here, let me known how you want to trigger you form on click where?

Comment: Because i dunno why you want to send 2 forms in the same time cos only can do the job, login and after success on you php page $_POST and then make your records as logs records.

Comment: I'm using login.php from the following page [link](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/HotSpot_external_login_page) but Im trying to add my new form in too so that the data entered in the form is also sent to a database in the external web server.

Comment: you can do it after the login inside the page php who doLogin() is calling, this is for an insert to a table "login_history"?

Comment: Hi there @headmax , were looking to log everything that the form processes. Even the unsuccessful login.